# Find one weaker condition on $\{c_k\}$ so that $T$ is well-defined

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\{f_k\}$ be a sequence of orthonormal basis. Let $c:=\{c_k\}$ be a sequence of complex numbers. Define linear operator $T$ as follows: for any $x\in H$,
$$
T: (x_1,x_2,\dots)\to (c_1x_1,c_2x_2,c_3x_3,\dots)
$$

I try to find one weaker condition on $\{c_k\}$ so that $T$ is well-defined. That means $Tx=\sum_k c_k\langle x, e_k\rangle e_k$ is convergent.

I can find one stronger condition so that $T$ is bounded.

Note that by Parseval identity
$$
\|Tx\|\le \sum_k |c_k\langle x,e_k\rangle|\le \sqrt{\sum_k c_k^2}\sqrt{\sum_k |\langle  x, e_k\rangle|^2}=\|c\|_2\|x\|
$$

If we assume that $\|c\|_2<\infty$, then $\|T\|<\infty$.

But this condition is stronger than what I want...

Comment: $T$ is the multiplication operator by $c$ on $\ell^2$, so we have $\|T\| = \|c\|_{\infty}$. It's at least easy that $\|cx\| \leq \|c\|_{\infty}\|x\|$ since $|c_jx_j| \leq \|c\|_{\infty}|x_j|$.

Comment: @Kakashi Yes, I know. If $\lim c_k\to 0$, then $T$ is compact... But I just want $T$ is well-defined. So I ask for weaker condition but not stronger one...

Comment: $\|c\|_{\infty} = \sup_{j}|c_j| < \infty$ is necessary and sufficient for $T$ to be bounded.

Comment: @Kakashi But how about $T$ is well-defined? Is it same as $T$ bounded?

Comment: @Hermi I think it is essentially the same. If $\|c\| =\infty$, you can find a subsequence $\left\lbrace c_{i_k} \right\rbrace$ such that $|c_{i_k}| >k$. Then you can find an element in $\ell^2$ such that $T(x)$ is a sequence with infinitely many number of entries equal to $1$, which implies $T(x)$ is not in $\ell^2$, hence not well-defined.

Comment: @Tri Ok, I see! Thanks.